# mod_rewrite rule for all except some specific paths

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

How do I write a mod_rewrite rule that is the opposite of this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/fixed_path/(page1|page2)([^/]+)$ /index.php?fixed_path/show/$2 [L]
```

That is, I want all pages in the form:

```
ignored_path/fixed_path/x
```

to redirect to

```
/index.php/fixed_path/show/x
```

where

- x is *not* equal to page1, page2 (and some other values)
- ignored_path is ignored in the new url
- fixed_path is carried over to the new url

ie, I want a rule to redirect everything in the form "ignored_path/fixed_path/x", except specific pages (page1, page2, etc.), which are handled properly by my web app already.

I'm trying to use ! and [^] syntax, but I don't quite understand how these work, especially when they involve words not single characters.

Comment: My answer regex matches all urls that are NOT `/blah/page1` or `/blah/page2`. To write the rule, we need to know what you want these "none-of-the-above" URLs to be rewritten to. i.e. Need more information...

Comment: I've added more details to the question to show what I want to do

Comment: I don't understand your desired query string: `?path/show/$1`. I think you need something more like: `?var=path/show` to get somthing into the `$_GET` superglobal. Yes? Also, is the `/something/` a fixed path prefix?

Comment: When you say "I want all pages except X and Y to redirect to...", is this because X and Y are actual files you want loaded directly?

Comment: 'something' can be anything ie, (.*), but 'path' is fixed, and 'some_param' is the parameter I want to pass onto the 'path/show/$1' query. X and Y page urls are handled elsewhere in the system and don't need to be matched by the htaccess file.

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want `blah/path/some_param` (but not the two special cases: `blah/path/page1` and `blah/path/page2`), to be redirected to `/newpath/show/some_param`, which is then rewritten to `index.php?var=/newpath/show/some_param` (so that the browser shows `/newpath/show/some_param` in the address bar)?

Comment: Yup, pretty much. I've reworded the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want `blah/path/some_param` (but not the two special cases: `blah/path/page1` and `blah/path/page2`), to be redirected to `/path/show/some_param`, which is then rewritten to `index.php?var=/path/show/some_param` (so that the browser shows /path/show/some_param in the address bar), then the following should do the trick:

```
# Check if we have the mod_rewrite module available...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^path/(?!page1$|page2$)([^/]+)$  http://yourdomain.com/path/show/$1 [R]
    RewriteRule ^(path/show/.*)$  index.php?var=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work. Are you allowed to have 2 $ like that?

Comment: Yes, you can have two `$` in a regex. p.s. I'm looking into updating this answer so that it will work for you. Standby...

Comment: Great thanks! That was very helpful in coming up with what I ended up using: RewriteRule ^(.+)/fixed_path/(?!page1$|page2$)([^/]+)$ /index.php?fixed_path/show/$2 [L]